# QGIS QChainage doesn't create point at intervals as I input

Tags: qgis

I want to create points at 10 meters intervals along the road, but when I input 10 meters into QChainage in QGIS as follows:

[image]

I got the points at 8.33333 meters intervals. I don't know why and how to create points at intervals that I want.

[image]

here is the information of my roadnet:

[image]

[image]

Comment: it's probably caused by the Spherical Mercator projection, try to re project your data to a CRS better suited for accurate measurement in your area

Comment: Identify one line with the ['Identify Features'](https://docs.qgis.org/3.4/en/docs/user_manual/introduction/general_tools.html#identify) tool. You will find the Cartesian (planimetric) length = 10m and the ellipsoidal length = 8.3...m. The difference is produced by the projection used, in that geographical place.